# Reinstalled XAMPP, now can't log in to phpMyAdmin/XAMPP not working

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, xampp

I reinstalled XAMPP and now it won't let me log in to phpMyAdmin with root.

I got it to stop giving me the "Connection for controluser as defined in your configuration failed." error, but it's still giving me "Cannot log in to the MySQL server"

The only thing I changed in my config.inc.php (which previously worked fine with my old version of XAMPP) is from `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'config';` to `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie';`

Here's the whole config.inc.php

```
<?php
/*
 * This is needed for cookie based authentication to encrypt password in
 * cookie
 */
$cfg['blowfish_secret'] = 'xampp'; /* YOU SHOULD CHANGE THIS FOR A MORE SECURE COOKIE AUTH! */

/*
 * Servers configuration
 */
$i = 0;

/*
 * First server
 */
$i++;

/* Authentication type and info */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = '';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysqli';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = true;
$cfg['Lang'] = '';

/* Bind to the localhost ipv4 address and tcp */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = '127.0.0.1';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type'] = 'tcp';

/* User for advanced features */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['controluser'] = '';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['controlpass'] = '';

/* Advanced phpMyAdmin features */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['pmadb'] = 'phpmyadmin';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['bookmarktable'] = 'pma__bookmark';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['relation'] = 'pma__relation';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['table_info'] = 'pma__table_info';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['table_coords'] = 'pma__table_coords';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['pdf_pages'] = 'pma__pdf_pages';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['column_info'] = 'pma__column_info';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['history'] = 'pma__history';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['designer_coords'] = 'pma__designer_coords';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['tracking'] = 'pma__tracking';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['userconfig'] = 'pma__userconfig';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['recent'] = 'pma__recent';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['table_uiprefs'] = 'pma__table_uiprefs';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['users'] = 'pma__users';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['usergroups'] = 'pma__usergroups';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['navigationhiding'] = 'pma__navigationhiding';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['savedsearches'] = 'pma__savedsearches';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['central_columns'] = 'pma__central_columns';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['designer_settings'] = 'pma__designer_settings';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['export_templates'] = 'pma__export_templates';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['favorite'] = 'pma__favorite';

/*
 * End of servers configuration
 */

?>
```

UPDATE:
I reinstalled phpMyAdmin again and now when I try to run Apache it gives me this:

```
Error: Apache shutdown unexpectedly.  
10:14:59 AM  [Apache]   This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies,   
10:14:59 AM  [Apache]   improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.  
10:14:59 AM  [Apache]   Press the Logs button to view error logs and check  
10:14:59 AM  [Apache]   the Windows Event Viewer for more clues  
10:14:59 AM  [Apache]   If you need more help, copy and post this  
10:14:59 AM  [Apache]   entire log window on the forums
```

Comment: And what do the logs say if you press the Logs button and look in the Event Viewer?

Answer (score 0):

Just to tick all the boxes - have you confirmed the root password hasn't been reset during the reinstallation? Try opening a shell and logging in - something to the effect of

```
mysql -u root -p
```

and enter the password at the prompt. If you get the mysql> shell prompt, it's not a username/password issue.